# Oracle sequence/number generation based on specific set of records in a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequences

I am fetching one particular result set using oracle query. In that I have a key which denotes the next set of records. I need to use the key and generate the sequence for those records.
For e.g. The oracle resultset looks like this without the sequence.

```
PROD_ID SEQUENCE TYPE      QUANTITY
1-9ER        200 Capsule         50
1-9ER        210 Tablet          80
1-9ER        220 Tonic           75
1-9ER        230 Injection       90
1-7OR        200 Capsule         80
1-7OR        210 Tablet          30
1-7OR        220 Tonic           15
1-7OR        230 Injection       20
```

So, I need to embed the sequnce through SQL select query and it should increment to the next set of 100 once it finds a different product ID. So, is it possible to write a query in oracle for this?
I am just using a general sequence in my query, but that does not solve my issue. Please provide me with ideas on how to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible in Oracle? YES. How? Analytic function.

Comment: Could you provide an example of expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select prod_id, 
       100 * dense_rank() over (order by prod_id) + row_number() over (partition by prod_id order by type) - 1 as seq_number,
       type,
       quantity
from products
order by prod_id, type;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d97c6/2

**Edit** after the question has been changed:

You can change the way the numbers are generated, by changing the use of the window functions:

```
select prod_id, 
       200 + row_number() over (partition by prod_id order by type) * 10 as seq_number,
       type,
       quantity
from products
order by prod_id, type;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d97c6/3

Comment: Hi,

Can we tweak the query to fetch the Sequence in such a way that the sequence would look more like a repeating one.
For e.g. 
PROD_ID SEQUENCE TYPE      QUANTITY
1-9ER        200 Capsule         50
1-9ER        201 Tablet          80
1-9ER        202 Tonic           75
1-9ER        203 Injection       90
1-7OR        200 Capsule         80
1-7OR        201 Tablet          30
1-7OR        202 Tonic           15
1-7OR        203 Injection       20

Thank you.

Comment: @Cool_Oracle: sorry I don't get it. The example outputs *exactly* what you have written in your question.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer.
However, I would like to increment the sequence by 10 and repeating the same sequence after it encounters a different PROD_ID. I made the change in my main question just for your reference to understand clearly.